# C# - WPF - Set random picture to <Image>

Tags: c#, wpf, image

How can I set random picture to WPF `<Image>`?

In my code I have 4 images.

Function `img1_Loaded_1` sets sources of the images like this:

The problem is that I would like 2 images to have the same picture. For example img1 and img4 would have the same picture and image2 would have different and img3 also would have different picture. At this moment I made it like this but I would like to set this picture to img1, img2 and so on dynamically. I would like also randomize which 2 of this 4 images would have the same picture.

Any ideas how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why make life difficult and have 2 images named differently that have the same picture?

Comment: yes, I can set identically the name of 2 images with the same picture but for example `img1` will always have `bitImages[0]` and I would like to randomize which of the last 3 images (`img2`, `img3`, `img4`) would have the same picture as `img1`

Comment: but why have the same pictures stored multiple times? Why not just reference the original one and save yourself the headache? It's like taking a picture of the same tree 5 times instead of taking 1 and just printing a few more times..

Comment: where do you see that I have stored the same picture multiple times ?

Comment: Your question: `For example img1 and img4 would have the same picture`. img1 and img4 have the **same** picture.

Comment: yes, but I have also said that for example `img1` will always have `bitImages[0]` and I would like to randomize which of last 3 images would have the same picture(`bitImages[0]`) like 'img1` so in one case it could be `img2` or in another `img4`, do you know what I mean ?

Comment: Generate a random number between 1 and 3 and assign the `bitImages[randomNumber]` the same image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have put this basic code together quickly, hopefully will set you on the right track. The code should sit in Window_Loaded or another similar high level container, as it only needs to be called once. Potentially you could do other things such as filtering the lists using LINQ (e.g. selecting Image controls will null sources). Let me know if you have any questions!

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set up lists to track which images / image controls have been used .. image resources and image controls will be removed from the relevant list once used.
        int imageCount = 4;
        IList<string> imageNames = new List<string>(imageCount) { "Image0", "Image1", "Image2", "Image3" };
        IList<Image> imageControls = new List<Image>(imageCount) { img1, img2, img3, img4 };

        //Pick an image resource at random to use as the one that will appear twice.
        Random random = new Random();
        int duplicatedImageIndex = random.Next(0, imageCount - 1);
        Uri duplicatedImageUri = new Uri("/rnd_pic;component/Images/" + imageNames[duplicatedImageIndex] + ".jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        //Select a random image control for first instance of image resource to be duplicated, then remove control from list to ensure it's not re-used.
        int firstDuplicatedImageControlIndex = random.Next(0, imageCount - 1);
        imageControls[firstDuplicatedImageControlIndex].Source = new BitmapImage(duplicatedImageUri);
        imageControls.RemoveAt(firstDuplicatedImageControlIndex);

        //Select a random image control for second instance of image resource to be duplicated, then remove control & image resource from relevant list to ensure they're not re-used.
        int secondDuplicatedImageControlIndex = random.Next(0, --imageCount - 1);
        imageControls[secondDuplicatedImageControlIndex].Source = new BitmapImage(duplicatedImageUri);
        imageControls.RemoveAt(secondDuplicatedImageControlIndex);
        imageNames.RemoveAt(duplicatedImageIndex);

        //loop through remaining image controls setting one of the remaining random images, removing control & image resource from relevant list as you go.
        while (imageControls.Any())
        {
            int randomUpperBound = --imageCount - 1;
            int nextRandomImageIndex = random.Next(0, randomUpperBound);
            int imageControlIndex = random.Next(0, randomUpperBound);
            Uri nextImageUri = new Uri("/rnd_pic;component/Images/" + imageNames[nextRandomImageIndex] + ".jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            imageControls[imageControlIndex].Source = new BitmapImage(nextImageUri);
            imageControls.RemoveAt(imageControlIndex);
            imageNames.RemoveAt(nextRandomImageIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, it seems to work, but now I have a problem. In the button click event I compare images sources like this `img0.Source == img2.Source` and they are the same but nothing happen

Comment: comparison of image sources works in button click event if I set image sources with my solution, when I use your solution button click event doesn't work

Comment: Could you let me know what you're trying to achieve with the comparison and the button click event? If you can paste your code, even better.